# HTC showing a weird screen?

Tags: screen, htc

Recently my HTC showed a weird screen. I wasn't on my phone at the time, but when I went to look at it, the screen was out of wack. I've never seen this in my life. I don't know if my phone is hacked or what. I wasn't able to get an actual photo of the screen, but it looked something like this: http://prnt.sc/emdogr . The screen was also animated. After this happened my phone sometimes turns on by itself. I'm hoping that it's something normal?? Is anyone else dealing with this or am I being hacked?

Answer (score 0):

What you saw is likely the HTC Dot View. It's an interface that works with certain protection sleeves, that shows time, notification and other info through a stylish, easy-to-read "dotted matrix".

[image]

However, if your phone isn't wearing such a sleeve when it happens, it's advised that you check for magnetic sources around it, which could trick the phone into thinking it's paired with such a sleeve. You said "After this happened my phone sometimes turns on by itself" - further reinforced my speculation that it's some (unstable) interference from a random magnetic source around.